# Anything similar to cone product formula (for convex polytopes)?

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, co.combinatorics, rt.representation-theory, convex-polytopes, intersection-cohomology

The convex polytope flag vector ring $\mathcal{R}$ satisfies the *cone product formula*
$$
 C(U) C(V) = C(J(U, V)) + DUV
$$
where
$$
 J(U, V) = U C(V) + C(U) V - e_1 UV
$$
is the *join formula*.

**Note:** Here $e_0 = 1$, $e_{n+1} = C(e_n)$ are the simplices. And $D = e_1e_1 - e_2$, the difference between a square and a triangle.

**Question:** Has anyone seen anything similar to this cone product formula?

**About:**
The rank zero component $\mathcal{R}_{[0]}$ of $\mathcal{R}$ is, roughly speaking, the representation ring of the Lie algebra $sl_2$ (as in the proof of hard Lefschetz). I'd be most delighted to know that $\mathcal{R}$ is similarly the representation ring of something.

**Hints:**

1. $\mathcal{R}$ is the universal commutative ring, generated by cone and product, that satisfies the cone product formula.
2. By a theorem of Bayer and Billera, $\mathcal{R}$ is a graded ring $\bigoplus_d\mathcal{R}_d$, with dimensions the Fibonacci numbers.
3. The (middle perversity) interesection homology Betti numbers of $X$ are a linear function of the flag vector $f(X)\in\mathcal{R}_d$, where $d=\dim X$. Are there other such Betti numbers?
4. Google search for *["cone product formula"](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22cone%20product%20formula%22)* didn't help me.

**See also:** my [preprint on the arxiv](https://arxiv.org/abs/1908.00039) and my [blog post](https://jfine2358.github.io/post/2019/07/31/lin-homy-nutshell-on-arxiv/).